# Bit Packing in Java

Tags: java, compression, bit

I am working on a compression algorithm.I am reading an image file of 8 bits/pixel and I want to pack these 8 bit values into 4 bits in order to compress.I want some useful insight into Bit Packing in Java and how can I approach this problem? I dont need a working solution.Just guidance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your actual compression algorithm?

Comment: @harold I will use quantization.Uniform quantization

Comment: Ok that makes sense, well then just make bytes out of those 4bit thing (take pairs, combine with `(a << 4) | b`), send the bytes

Comment: @harold thanks. Can you give me the algorithm? Where to start? Let us say I am reading a .ppm file with 8 bit pixel values,how to pack them into 4 bits?

Comment: @Shehlina making them into 4 bit things in the first place is what your compression algorithm will do, so in a sense that's your problem (you could take the upper 4 bits of every byte perhaps, in the simplest case)

Comment: @harold thanks! Can I write a method to implement my quantization algorithm? I mean I just want to understand the flow here.

Comment: I have the step size of this quantizer and I have implemented my quantizer using a paper and pencil.But my only problem is implementing that logic here.I am sure it is not rocket science so I approached this forum for a little start.

Answer (score 1):

Your compression routine could look as follows:

```
void compress(byte[] pic, byte[] picCompressed) {
    boolean odd = false;
    int pos = 0;

    for (byte p : pic)
    {
        byte b = quantize(p);

        if (odd) {
            picCompressed[pos++] |= (byte)(b << 4);
        } else {
            picCompressed[pos] = b;             
        }

        odd = !odd;
    }       
}
```

The original array is traversed in a loop. Controlled by an alternating `odd` variable, the compressed 4 bits are stuffed either in the upper or in the lower half of the byte position in the compressed array.

A simplistic quantizing routine would just ignore the lower 4 bits:

```
byte quantize(byte p) {
    return (byte)((p >> 4) & 0x0F);
}
```

In practice, quantizing is non-uniform and often implemented using a look-up table. You could use an array of 256 bytes to assign a target value to every possible byte value.

Comment: Running this code converts byte values {0,1,2,3,4,5} into {0,0,0,0,0}. Is it achieving the compression?

Comment: @Shehlina: all byte values below 15 are quantized to 0. Therefore, you are getting all zero bytes. Use a different quantization or bigger values to see a difference.

Comment: Thanks. I used bigger array values (240,241,242,242), still getting all zeroes.What do u mean when u said "USe a different quantization"? Can you provide an example?

Comment: My quantize() routine converts 240 (hex 0xF0) to 15 (hex 0x0F). No clue why this should result in 0.

Comment: Yup I got that too.Thanks! But what does your following statement in compress subroutine do?                               { picCompressed[pos++] |= (byte)(b << 4);}

Comment: The shift "<<" moves the bits of b four positions up. "<< 4" is equivalent to "*16". The "|=" performs a bit-wise OR with the array element value. They are all known to be 0 from the previous non-odd step. Bottom line: The lower 4 bit of b are taken as the upper 4 bit of the array element. "pos++" increments the array index by one. Sorry for the compact form, but this is not uncommon for practical source code.

Answer (score -1):

Java has operators to test/manipulate the bits of a number. Take a look at this:

[Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

If you need to handle a larger amount of bits, there is also the [`Bitset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) class.

Basically what you need is just the bitwise operators to test/manipulate the bits of variables of either `byte` or `int` type.